# Group and send message to Client in static method

Tags: c#, signalr, static-methods, signalr-hub, object-reference

I have a class GroupManager, and during the process I would like to group people and send them a message from a static method, is it possible ?

Here is my class GroupManager

```
public class GroupManager: Hub
{
    // The dictionnary contains <userName, conectionId>
    private static Dictionary<string, string> _reference { get; set; }

    private static void CreateRoom(string roomName)
    {
        foreach (var user in _reference)
        {
            // error
            Groups.Add(user.Value, roomName);
            Clients.Group(roomName).sendMessageToClient("user connected : " + user.Key);
        }
    }
}
```

When I call the **Groups.Add**...

There is an error :

> *an object reference is required for the non-static fields, methods or properties*

The same error with **Clients.Group**...

I understand the problem, but I don't know how to get the object reference of the Hub.

Thanks

EDIT :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show your `Clients` class and `Group` method implementations also..

Comment: I didn't write the Groups and Clients methods, they come from the Hub class inheritance

Comment: I edit the post for adding the screenshot of the 2 method references

Answer (score 1):

Why make CreateRoom static? If it's operating on static data, you don't need it to be static (and by making it static, it can't operate on instance data).

If you need to access the hub from outside the hub itself, see the following:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub

Answer (score 0):

Remove the key word "static" from your dictionary property and CreateRoom method.

Static methods can't operate on instance data, which is the issue.